# Why std::void_t is required to detect ill-formed types in SFINAE context?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, void-t

I have `is_callable` trait as below:

```cpp
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_callable: std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>>: std::true_type {};  // (A)
```

There I have to wrap `decltype(&T::operator())` with `std::void_t` rather than use just the `decltype` itself like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct is_callable<T, decltype(&T::operator())>: std::true_type {};  // (B)
```

If I use just the `decltype` itself (B) then I got no compilation error thus I assume that `decltype` is still in SFINAE context but the detection does not work - the trait value is always false. Can someone explain how exactly `void_t` helps here.

Comment: The duplicate target covers the whole `void_t` issue quite well. Take some time to read through that, and if you have a more specific question that's not covered there, go ahead and edit this question, then ping me, and I'll reevaluate.

Comment: `decltype(&T::operator())` is never `void`, it would be `Ret (T::*)(Args...) /*const volatile &&*/`, so you don't specialize `is_callable<T, void>`, so continue to use primary template.  `decltype(&T::operator(), void())` would behave as expected.